# card in bulma is not working as the way it has to work

Tags: reactjs, graphql, bulma

I am trying to make bulma cards to render my PostPreview components. Something like this in inline form.

[image: card display]

But its not working this way

> Here is my code 
>   PostPreview.js

```
import React from 'react'


function postPreview(props) {
    console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="card__wrapper">
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-image">
                <figure className="image is-4by3">
                    <img src={props.imageURL} alt={props.title}/> 
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div className="card-content">
                <div className="media-content">
                    <p className="title is-4">{props.title}</p>
                    <p className="subtitle is-6">@johnsmith</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Phasellus nec iaculis mauris. <a>@bulmaio</a>.
                <a href="#">#css</a> <a href="#">#responsive</a>
                <br/>
                <time datetime="2016-1-1">{props.date}</time>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default postPreview
```

I am getting data from graphql.

My code show me something like this.

this is the sandbox link[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/adityakmr7/wordpress-blog)

This is the result.

[image: image result]

Comment: Please paste the problematic results directly here in the question, not just in a link.

Comment: okay i did update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your cards to be in columns you need to wrap them in a container with `className="columns"` and give your post preview a `className="column"` with a width, e.g. `is-one-quarter` to have 4 cards in each row.

**Example**

```
const PostPreview = ({title, imageURL, date}) => (
    <div className="card__wrapper column is-one-quarter"> {/* apply 'column class here' */}
        <div className="card">
            {/* ... */}       
        </div>
    </div>
);

const Posts = () => (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="columns is-multiline"> {/* apply 'columns' class here */}
            <PostPreview title="post 1" imageURL="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
            <PostPreview title="post 2" imageURL="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
            <PostPreview title="post 3" imageURL="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
            <PostPreview title="post 4" imageURL="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
            <PostPreview title="post 5" imageURL="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
            <PostPreview title="post 6" imageURL="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

[image: Edit v865l37lnl]

Also see [Columns powered by Flexbox](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/basics/)
 in the bulma docs.

In your case you need to apply that on the `div` of your `postRenderer` component.